# Which endpoint to connect to for read/write operations using AWS Aurora PostgreSQL Database Cluster

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have an application (AWS API Gateway) using an Aurora PostgreSQL cluster.

The cluster has 1 read/write (primary) and one reader endpoint.

At the moment, my application connections to the specific writer instance for all operations:
rds-instance-1.xxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com

But I have the following endpoints available:

```
rds.cluster-xxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com    
rds.cluster-ro-xxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com
rds-instance-1.xxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com 
rds-instance-1-ap-southeast-2c.xxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

If I am doing read and write operations, should I be connecting to the instance endpoint I'm using? Or should i use rds.cluster-xxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com ?  What are the benefits of using the different endpoints? I understand that if I connect to a read only endpoint I can only do reads, but for read/writes what's the difference connecting to:

```
rds.cluster-xxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

Or

```
rds-instance-1.xxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

?

What is the right / best endpoint to use for general workloads, and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use cluster reader/writer endpoint.

```
rds.cluster-xxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com    
rds.cluster-ro-xxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

The main benefit of using cluster endpoint is that if the [failover](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html) occurs due to some reason you will not worry about the endpoint and you will can expect a minimal interruption of service.

Or what if you have 3 read replica then how you will manage to connect the reader? so Better to use cluster reader/writer endpoint.

**Using the Reader Endpoint**

> You use the reader endpoint for read-only connections for your Aurora
> cluster. This endpoint uses a load-balancing mechanism to help your
> cluster handle a query-intensive workload. The reader endpoint is the
> endpoint that you supply to applications that do reporting or other
> read-only operations on the cluster.

**Using the Cluster Endpoint**

> You use the cluster endpoint when you administer your cluster, perform
> extract, transform, load (ETL) operations, or develop and test
> applications. The cluster endpoint connects to the primary instance of
> the cluster. The primary instance is the only DB instance where you
> can create tables and indexes, run INSERT statements, and perform
> other DDL and DML operations.

**Instance endpoint**

> The instance endpoint provides direct control over connections to the
> DB cluster, for scenarios where using the cluster endpoint or reader
> endpoint might not be appropriate. For example, your client
> application might require more fine-grained load balancing based on
> workload type. In this case, you can configure multiple clients to
> connect to different Aurora Replicas in a DB cluster to distribute
> read workloads. For an example that uses instance endpoints to improve
> connection speed after a failover for Aurora PostgreSQL

You can check furhter details [AWS RDS Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.html)

Comment: >> You should use cluster reader/writer endpoint. Specifically, are you referring to "rds.cluster-xxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com (writer)" for the op's question? Or are you referring to write job->writer(rds.cluster-xxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com), read job->reader(rds.cluster-ro-xxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com)  which is to split in application side ?

Comment: if you click on RDS, it will provide two endpoints. 
Reader: for the select etc and Writer for writing to Database. the reader contain `ro`,

Comment: You can, additionally, have the RDS Proxy layer. It'll queue requests and manage connections so you never have downtime (but may have increased latency). It's not cheap though. https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/